# How to remove directory's write permission in linux?

Tags: linux

I saw:

```
chmod o-rwx somefile
```

This will remove read/write/execute permissions from other users (doesn't include users within your group).

How can I remove write permission only for current user?

Comment: `chmod u-w`? Really: you should start reading the "man pages" in Linux: `man chmod`...

Comment: I strongly recommend https://explainshell.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions in linux are given for user (who is the owner of the file), group (which is the group of the owner of file by default (though youcan change using `chgrp` command)) and others. Every file has 3 permissions for each of these categories (Read, Write and Execute), which are represented by setting or unsetting of corresponding bits. So, permissions range from 0 to 7, where 0 is no permission, 1 is x, 2 is w, 3 is wx, 4 is r, 5 is rx, 6 is rw and 7 is rwx. 
So, use `chmod abc filename` where a/b/c are numbers in range 0-7 for user, group and others respectively.